# Ignoring Index, default to sorting issue

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

```sql
SELECT 
    count(
        DISTINCT concat(
            country,
            col1,
            fcol1,
            mcol1,
            col2,
            fcol2,
            mcol2,
            col3,
            fcol3,
            mcol3,
            col4,
            fcol4,
            col5,
            fcol5
        )
    ) AS count_1, 
    date_part('year', created_on) AS year,
    date_part('month', created_on) AS month 
FROM tabel1 
WHERE 
    successful = true AND
    owner_id = 2132611397  AND
    created_on BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2023-01-01'
 GROUP BY 2, 3;
```

I' am performing this query on 800k rows, and it's taking ~ 6.6s to resolve, despite having index on `(date_part('year', created_on), date_part('month', created_on))`.

When I perfrom an explain to this query, it shows that the planner is ignoring the index and is defaulting to do sort with keys `date_part('year', created_on), date_part('month', created_on)`.

How can i speed up this query?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're thinking about how SQL works the *wrong way round*.

***First*** it locates a set of rows/tuples on which to operate (based on your FROM and JOIN clauses, etc.) and ***only then*** does it try to *do* anything *with* those rows (SELECT data out of them, UPDATE them, or whatever).

Having indexes on the bits you're *selecting* won't help, because that part comes *after* the rows to work with have been found.  You don't have *any* indexes that can support a query filtering by `owner`, `created_on` and/or `successful` so, yes; it's Table-Scanning.

Having index(es) on these three fields will be a lot more help.  The exact order of that index will depend on your own data but I would *guess* that { `owner`, `created_on` } would be a good place to start.

As ever, try it and see ...

Comment: May as well throw `successful` into that composite index.  (But before `created_at`.)